# How to make your XAML views flexible and customizable for users?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Our manager want the WPF application we are working on to be fully customizable for the user. So let's say there is a textbox on a page. He wants the user to be able to put it in any position he wants, make it have any color  or fontsize he wants, etc. Right now the implementation for this is to store every property in a SQL database and then build the view in your code behind.

This is a terrible implementation in my opinion because it slows the entire process down. When I navigate pages there is a loading time of at least 10 seconds where the code behind gets all the properties, turns them into objects, implement the objects into a view and then create that view. I think there must be a better way to do this, because it's sucking up so much  time and resources. Are there any better implementations for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of ways to do it, but if you need to have "everything changeable" then.. there's one quick way to do it, and even without any external tools.

By default, XAML is compiled and included in the .exe/.dll, but XAML can be loaded dynamically from a file/string/whatever. Put the XAML in a text file (it already is), change the compilation options to not compile it, but include as "content" and "copy always", load that file dynamically ([XmlReader.Load method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590388.aspx)).

Now users can edit the XAML, application will listen to it.

Of course:

- the app/window/etc will need to be reloaded/restarted after every change to the file
- they can now change *everything* in the UI layer
- they have to edit the file properly, they will probably need some basic training
- your app *may* get a bit more complex, because it will be now harder to find correct controls on the UI, but if you use VM and Bindings and Commands, then you are inherently safe against that problem (and if you dont use that approach, then .. consider starting)

Comment: Yeah that was what I was thinking as well. But I was a bit skeptical but you convinced  me that it's probably the best method.

Comment: i'm dreading to think about users (with or without basic training) who can edit the xaml. simple example: ui element has a style with a default backcolor and a trigger which changes backcolor under some condion. then a user comes and write `Backround = "White"` on ui element, ignoring style. the next thing happens is 100 bug reports about not working trigger. On the other side, Visual Studio IDE is a good example of customizable environment (with movable and pinnable windows and a nice Tools\Options\Enviroment\Fonts and Colors settings dialog)

Comment: @ASh: The same can be said about current approach - just imagine the users editing the config-database and moving buttons to positions (+34000,+23000) or setting background:white and textcolor:whitesmoke. Considering *[manager, who] wants the user to be able to put [controls] in any position he wants, make it have any color or fontsize he wants, etc*, this actually is a low-cost low-effort way to either perfectly achieve the goal if they really want it that way (their 'users' may actually have the time and technical skills, right?), or make the manager rethink his approach and requirements.

Comment: ..plus it removes huge amount of complexity of handling all customizations via database, and also allows the customizations to be easily tracked/branched by a vcs like git, what is quite cumbersome and error-prone with (manually?) handled db-based storage (where it probably is kept as screen-key-value table..).I've been there, I've seen it, and unless a lot of power is spent to provide the users with some sort of WYSIWYG ui editor, I'd actually opt for this way (or similar, i.e. they could edit a filtered/simplified xaml, which would be then joined/merged with original, etc.. tons of options)